# Backup data while keeping POSIX ACLs and permissions

Tags: linux, backup, debian, permissions, access-control-list

I'm looking for a practical way to backup data from a server and keep all ACLs and permissions. I've looked at tar, but according to Google tar doesn't keep ACLs . I know rsync can keep ACLs and permissions, but only if the target system supports POSIX ACLs and have the same users. In my case I'm doing the backup to a directory that is located on AFS, so POSIX ACLs are not supported.

At the moment I have solved the problem by writing a script that uses find to recurse through the system (I'm using find because I which to exclude some directories) and saves the permissions and ACLs to a text file. This solution works, but is painfully slow. Is there a better solution?

Comment: See also [this duplicate question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/391/30196).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
apt-get install star
man star
star -acl -whatever -other -options -you -need
```

Star is tar with support for extended POSIX headers, that is, the ability to store some extra data about a file in the tar file.  The `-acl` option gets the ACLs; you need it for both archive creation and extraction.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to install another program, you can backup the ACLs separately:

```
getfacl -R somedir > acls.txt
```

This dumps all the ACLs from `somedir` into the file `acls.txt`.

To restore, use:

```
setfacl -R --set-file=acls.txt somedir
```

Comment: +1 for something I just didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

beside star you can use [bsdtar](http://packages.debian.org/stable/bsdtar)

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/725745/550161

---

When creating/extracting the archive you need to use both the `--acls` **and** `--xattrs` options and of-course have the proper permissions to read/write those [acl](/questions/tagged/acl) and [xattr](/questions/tagged/xattr).

### Examples:

#### 1. Creating the archive:

```
ZSTD_CLEVEL=19 tar --acls --xattrs -caPf systemd-network-conf.tzst --directory=/etc systemd/network systemd/networkd.conf.d
```

The above will create a `zstd` compressed `tar` archive, using compression level `19`, while preserving the ACL's and extended attributes.

- The `.tzst` extension means "a [tar](/questions/tagged/tar) archive using [zstd](/questions/tagged/zstd) compression", just like `tgz` is for a [gzip](/questions/tagged/gzip)'ed version etc.
- The compression level used by the implicit `zstd` compressor is set by the provided `ZSTD_CLEVEL` environment variable at start on same line.
- See man pages: `tar(1)` and `zstd(1)`.

#### 2. Extracting that archive:

```
sudo tar --acls --xattrs -xvf systemd-network-conf.tzst
```

The above will create, in your current directory, a sub-directory named `systemd` because that's the common root-dir inside the archive.

- All settings you had set using [chown](/questions/tagged/chown)/[chmod](/questions/tagged/chmod)/[setfacl](/questions/tagged/setfacl) in the originals, will be preserved in the extracted version.

#### 3. Comparing original and extracted file attributes.

```shell
{cd /etc; getfacl -R systemd/network systemd/networkd.conf.d} >original.acl; cd -
getfacl -R systemd/network systemd/networkd.conf.d >extracted.acl
diff -u original.acl extracted.acl
```

- You should see no output from the first two lines because it is redirected to a file.
  *(Exception for first line, which will output your current directory due to the last `cd -` as separate command, which just restores your current directory.)*
- You should see no output from the diff line either, because there's no difference.